# Parsing repeating groups from a string

Tags: java, string, parsing, nested

I'm currently taking in a string which is being dividing

```
20004=1~^20005=0~^773=~^665=~^453=3~^448=0A~!447=D~!452=1~!~^448=0A~!447=D~!452=17~!~^448=81~!447=D~!452=7~!~^11=1116744Pq2Q~^70=15040024-1~^793=MNL-?--1~^467=37878024-1~^60=20110617-05:57:31~^75=20110616~^768=1~^769=20110616-19:17:00~!770=1~!~^55=7800950~^48=AEP~^22=~^454=0~^460=5~^167=TCKR~^
```

The makeup of the string is such that ~^ divides attributes and ~! marks groups. Groups have an attribute preceding them which tells the number of repeating groups such like

```
453=3~^448=0A~!447=D~!452=1~!~^448=0A~!447=D~!452=17~!~^448=81~!447=D~!452=7~!~^
```

Where tag 453 denotes that there are 3 groups.

I was using a parse such as this:

```
    public Map<Integer, Object> parse(Object target)
{
    String[] elements = ((String) target).split(elementDilimiter);

    Map<Integer, Object> targetFields = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Object>();

    for(int i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
    {
        String[] attributes = elements[i].split(attributeDelimiter);


        if(attributes.length != 2 || attributes[0].length() == 0 || attributes[1].length() == 0)
        {
            /*throw new ParsingException("Malformed element: " + element + ", expected: tag=value");*/
            continue;
        }
            targetFields.put(Integer.valueOf(attributes[0]), attributes[1]);
    }
    return targetFields;
}
```

Element delimiter = ~^ and Attribute delimiter = "="

So after the line:

```
String[] elements = ((String) target).split(elementDilimiter);
```

The Values are split as follows

```
453=3, 448=0A~!447=D~!452=1~!, 448=0A~!447=D~!452=17~!, 448=81~!447=D~!452=7~!,
```

These are then split on equals and placed within a map using the tagNo to return a the revelant object.

However when the groups get to:

```
String[] attributes = element.split(attributeDelimiter);
```

The groups go no further due to:

```
attributes.length != 2
```

But Ideally I would like my implementation to be able to grab the tag 453 realise there is 3 repeating groups, repeating groups go into a parser which will split them delimited on ~! and placed within a sub map.

Now I will be honest when I think of implementation my head starts to spin.

Is there a simple eligant solution around this or is it basic start from scratch.

**EDIT**

Is 453 defined to always be the identifier for the number of groups? 
yes the tag before the groups merely tells me how many groups there will be. I have no control of the incoming string or it's format it will take the form as above.

What do your groups represent - I ask this one because I would have thought attributes are together as part of groups, but in your method you split on attributes but not groups and you split on elements before attributes? 
I split the elements so that they can be separated as 453=3 etc however then this group business came in. So now I must rewrite to accomodate them too. This is in essence my problem before hand I had lovely tag values that mapped to a object and could be accessed simply via:

```
targetFields.get(TagNumber);
```

Now I will need to rewrite to enable accessibility to the groups!

I hope this cleared things a bit

Comment: I don't think you have explained the problem well enough. Why do you need both a delimiter pattern to separate groups and a tag also specifying how many groups there are? Is 453 defined to always be the identifier for the number of groups? What do your groups represent - I ask this one because I would have thought attributes are together as part of groups, but in your method you split on attributes but not groups **and** you split on elements *before* attributes? This is confusing; I think you have set something up that is not self explanatory, so you need to fully explain it.

Comment: I edited it to answer your questions I hope it will clarify some of the confusion

Comment: Still not clear.  In one place you say `The makeup of the string is such that ~^ divides attributes and ~! marks groups` while further down you say `Element delimiter = ~^ and Attribute delimiter = "="`... which is it?

Comment: because the number to the left hand side of the value pair such as 453=3 is static, It is only the values to the right that changes. ~! refers that this is an element with a group of numbers that can repeat n amount of times.
The number to the right only identifies the value to the right is what I will be assigning within a new object. I am only controlling mapping between these two objects not the structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will parse out the groups/subgroups.  You can replace the system.print statements with your map building.  You may want to rethink the format, however, because it could be a lot clearer if you used a format that naturally supports nesting like XML

```
@Test
public void testname() throws Exception {
    parseText("453=3~^448=0A~!447=D~!452=1~!~^448=0A~!447=D~!452=17~!~^448=81~!447=D~!452=7~!~^");
}

private int subgroupLength = 0;

public void parseText(String text) {
    for (String group : text.split("~\\^")) {
        System.out.println("Group");
        parseGroup(group);
    }
}

public void parseGroup(String group) {
    for (String attribute : group.split("~!"))
        parseAttribute(attribute);
}

public void parseAttribute(String attribute) {
    String[] split = attribute.split("=");
    if (split.length != 2)
        return;

    if (split[0].equals("453")) {
        System.out.println("\tSubgroup length " + split[1]);
        subgroupLength = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
    } else if (subgroupLength > 0) {
        subgroupLength--;
        System.out.println("\t\t" + split[0] + " = " + split[1]);
    } else
        System.out.println("\t" + split[0] + " = " + split[1]);
}
```

Comment: I need them to be held in a data structure

Comment: So create a data structure...?

Answer (score 0):

Use String.split in two steps.
First split the groups. The after split the attributes for each group.

It will solve your problem.